# Pass several values between view controllers with delegates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I've succesfully managed to pass one piece of data (one String variable, one Int variable etc.) between view controllers with delegate functions. However, I haven't managed to pass various pieces of data through delegate functions.

I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7faea770db60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key receivingAmountLabel.'
```

If I delete the `receingAmountLabel`, the error goes to another UI element. If I remove that element, it continues to another.

All UI elements are connected as they should be. The relevant piece of code look like this:

**FirstVC.swift**
class FirstVC: UIViewController, DataSentDelegateMax {

```
@IBOutlet weak var receivingStringLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var receivingAmountLabel: UILabel!

func userDidEnterData(stringData: String, amountData: Int) {
    receivingStringLabel.text = stringData
    receivingAmountLabel.text = String(amountData)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showSecondVC") {
        let secondVC = segue.destination as! SecondVC
        secondVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

**SecondVC.swift**

```
protocol DataSentDelegateMax {
    func userDidEnterData(stringData: String, amountData: Int)
}

    @IBOutlet weak var stringTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTF: UITextField!

    var delegate: DataSentDelegateMax? = nil

    @IBAction func sendButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if delegate != nil {
            if (stringTF.text != nil) {
                if (Int(amountTF.text!) != nil) {
                    let stringData = stringTF.text
                    let amountData = Int(amountTF.text!)
                    delegate?.userDidEnterData(stringData: stringData!, amountData: amountData!)
                    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the same problem when trying to pass a dictionary in the delegate.

Comment: You didn't set the correct class of of the `UIViewController` in Interface Builder. It's sill a `UIViewController`, not a `FirstVC`. If this was due to a misworking connection (renamed, etc.) it should have `[< FirstVC 0x7faea770db60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:` not `[<UIViewController 0x7faea770db60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:`

Comment: Can you try again by removing and connecting the IBOutlets again?

Comment: This error normally happens when the IBOutlets in the xib or storyboard are invalid (if they were set up then renamed or removed etc...). As previously suggested, check your IB file for invalid references.

Comment: @Larme, it was put right, but I changed custom class for both View Controllers and then changed back to FirstVC respectively SecondVC and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below simplified code:

```
   if let del = delegate, let stringData = stringTF.text, let amountData = amountTF.text  {
        del.userDidEnterData(stringData: stringData, amountData: amountData)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Not solution to the problem, but thanks for the piece of advice.

Answer (score 0):

make sure receivingAmountLabel outlet is connected to FirstVC